# Can I read a tome in Other Worlds?

Tags: arkham-horror

In Arkham Horror, tomes require movement points to use, e.g. Old Journal:

> ***Tome***
>   **Movement:** Exhaust and spend 1 movement point to make a **Lore (-1) check**. If you pass, gain 3 Clue tokens and discard Old Journal. If you fail, nothing happens.

Because I never receive movement points in Other Worlds, **is it possible to use a tome**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [FAQ on Fantasy Flights website](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD8QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fantasyflightgames.com%2Fffg_content%2FArkham_Horror%2FAHfaq.pdf&ei=8L3NUImyNKz8iQKIooCIBg&usg=AFQjCNHSH_R-xjFhGE0CTmevXLzldgrgkw&sig2=63-gee7gmvQ_W8znY4SJ-g) covers this question.

> Q: Characters in Other Worlds receive no movement points. But if a character in an Other World has an item that gives them movement points, such as the Motorcycle or Ruby of R' lyeh, can the character use an item that requires the character to spend movement points, such as the Necronomicon?
>
> **A: No. You can not receive movement points or use any item requiring movement points while in an Other World.**